# Pass custom data structures to C via Haskell FFI

Tags: function, haskell, types, ffi

If I have a C function that looks like this

```c
void print_addr(struct sockaddr_rc addr) {
    // some printing machinery
}
```

If I have defined a similar datastructure to `struct sockaddr_rc` in Haskell and implemented a `Storable` instance for it, is that enough to be able to define a foreign function like this?

```
foreign import ccall "print_addr" print_addr :: RFSocketAddress -> IO ()
```

I understood this to be the case, but I get an error telling me that there's an unacceptable argument in the foreign declaration, as `RFSocketAddress` can not be marshalled.

Comment: This https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_cook_book has a scetion on structs. Does that help?

Comment: @g_bor I looked briefly and it doesn't seem like it. They show some examples where they use hsc2hs.

Comment: I don't remember but I looked at my old code, and I've seen I always used `Ptr` for storable data structures. Isn't it `Ptr RFSocketAddress`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I was considering this as well. I reasoned that I can call C functions that have normal C integers as arguments and not pointers to C integers. I should be able to do the same with any type as long as I guide GHC enough?

Comment: I recall that GHC (or rather Haskell 2010) does not allow types other than “marshallable types” to be used as parameter types in FFI functions. Marshallable types include pointers but not (yet?) structs, even with `Storable` instances.

Comment: @krantz this makes it very clear, exactly what I was wondering :) Thanks!